# Similar Django url patterns matches wrong one

Tags: regex, django, url-pattern

It might be a regex issue or rule I'm not familiar with but I essentially have these 2 urls

```
(r'quote', quote),
(r'email/quote/$', sendQuote),
```

But when I go to **mydomain.com/email/quote** it keeps getting caught by the first one. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the start of the regex using the `^` character. Similar to how `$` specifies that it's the end of the regex, `^` will say that it's the start.

```
(r'^quote/$', quote),
(r'^email/quote/$', sendQuote),
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it has to do with order. `quote` matches `email/quote`, so it gets matched first (ignoring `email/quote/$`).  Try naming most-specific routes first, ending in a catch-all (if necessary):

```
(r'email/quote/$', sendQuote),
(r'quote', quote),
(r'.*', catchAll),
```

Comment: Wait, how would I write it so quote ONLY matches "quote" or "quote/"?

Comment: @user1561753, `quote/?$`, use an anchor to force it to the end of the string..the `?` makes it optional.